# custom taxonomy relationship

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm customizing wordpress by creating several taxonomies for a website.

Actually, I created 'Services' custom post type with several taxonomy in it. Then, I'm going to create 'Case History' custom post type where I'd like to re-use 'Service' posts.

I can show them on the backend (Case History add new item) by using WP_Query, but I had problems in saving them. So i've this doubt: is it possible to create a relationship between two different taxonomies? Is it possible to do that? Maybe I'm wrong somewhere ...

**update**: maybe it would be better if I explain this question this way. Can i use a custom post type ('Service') as a taxonomy inside another custom post type ('Custom post type') ?

**update2**: thx guys. I did solve my problem by using [this plugin (cpt onomies)](http://rachelcarden.com/cpt-onomies)

Comment: So are you trying to use the same taxonomies for both custom post types that you've created?  Is that the question?

Comment: I'm trying to use a custom post type as a custom taxonomy in another custom post type

Answer (score 2):

Taxonomies can be shared among multiple post types, but if you're looking for post types relationships, you can try using the [Types plugin (free) with the Views plugin (premium)](http://wp-types.com/) or code the functionality from Types. I've just started playing around with this and it enables easy creation of [relationships between post types](http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-post-type-relationships/).

Their example: you can have post types Cars and People and use post type Rental Agreement to link the two in many-to-many or one-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin might fit your needs if you're willing to simply relate 1 post type's post(s) to another post type's post(s). I'm not sure if it is exactly what you need, but it has been immensely helpful to me. There's a lot of power here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/